# Delete files after awk command

Tags: shell, aws-cli

I'm setting to do an ls in a bucket.
Make a print in folder name
remove the /, do sorting and remove the last 3.
which will be the most recent, then I'm setting remove the folds except for those 3 recent ones.

```
for i in $(aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site | awk -F '-' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\///g'| sort -n| tail -3| xargs| sed 's/ /|/g'); 
do aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site| grep -Ev "PRE\s.*\-($i)\/" | awk '{print $2}'|xargs echo "aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/"; done
```

I expect the output is exec

```
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/2e5d0599-120/
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/6f08a223-118/
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/ba67667e-121/
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/ba67667e-122/
```

but the actual is

```
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/2e5d0599-119/ 2e5d0599-120/ 6f08a223-118/ ba67667e-121/ ba67667e-122/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `xargs` you can try to compose your second `aws ls` command in `awk` and send it to `bash`:

```
aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site| grep -Ev "PRE\s.*\-($i)\/" | awk '{print "aws s3 ls s3://portal-storage-site/" $2}'| bash
```